# How to run Simperium unit tests on iOS

Tags: ios, unit-testing, simperium

The [Simperium Android Github](https://github.com/Simperium/simperium-android) tells how to run the Android tests, but I can't find how to run the iOS tests.  I tried opening Simperium.xcodeproj but Product->Test is grayed out.

Eventually I'd like to write my own unit tests that use Simperium, but I thought I'd start by looking into how Simperium structures their tests.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The process you describe adds Simperium's Integration Tests target to your own app's schema.

Normally, you would want to switch to the 3rd party library scheme first, and run the tests right there. To do so, please, click the Scheme picker (right by the Play / Stop buttons), and select 'Simperium'.

Make sure to select a simulator as well, since Tests are not supported in the real device.

Regarding failures, the Integration Tests simulate real interaction with the backend, and have several Timeouts.

Would it be possible you're running them on a slow internet connection?.

Thanks!

[image: Select Simperium Scheme]

[image: Select Simulator]

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to run the tests.  In Xcode, I selected the Integration Tests scheme and edited that scheme.  I selected 'Test' on the left side, then clicked the little plus at the bottom of the main pane.  I added the 'Integration Tests' target.  The list of tests to run appeared in the pane, and Product->Test could then be used to run the tests.

Unfortunately, 9 of the integration tests failed when I ran them.